# Establishing Socket connection between Android and UWP app over WiFiDirect

Tags: android, sockets, uwp, wifi-direct

I am trying to establish a socket connection between an **Android** and a **UWP** application over **WiFiDirect**. UWP application advertise itself enabling others to discover it. Android app search for available WiFiDirect device and connect with the UWP application.

I am successful in initialising and connecting over WiFiDirect between Android and UWP. But I am **confused about creating Socket connection** after WiFiDirect connection is made. More specifically I am hesitant on which side should i create `ServerSocket` and `client-socket`.

In Android side i have seen example of creating `ServerSocket` if the device is `group-owner` and vice-versa. But in UWP side I am not sure which one should i create.

Android side code to create socket:-

```
override fun onConnectionInfoAvailable(info: WifiP2pInfo?) {
    if (info!!.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
        // Creating ServerSocket
    }
    else if (info.groupFormed) {
        // Creating Client Socket
    }
}
```

On UWP side after connection request is received my sample code:-

```
private async void Listener_ConnectionRequestedAsync(
      WiFiDirectConnectionListener sender, 
      WiFiDirectConnectionRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        WiFiDirectConnectionRequest request = args.GetConnectionRequest();
        WiFiDirectDevice _device = await WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(request.DeviceInformation.Id);
        var endPoints = _device.GetConnectionEndpointPairs();
        EndpointPair firstEndpoint = endPoints[0];

        // Which socket connection should i create
        // StreamSocket or StreamSocketListener
    }
```

I have tried a **hack** in UWP which seems to work but I am **not confident** about it

```
if (firstEndpoint.LocalHostName.CanonicalName.EndsWith("1"))
{
  // creating server socket
  // StreamSocketListener and waiting for incoming connection                         
}
else
{
  //Creating client socket
  // StreamSocket and connecting with remote host                     
}
```

How should i decide create socket connection type in UWP side? Please provide the fundamental concept that i am missing here.

Comment: Hello, `StreamSocketListener` is usually used in UWP to cooperate with `WiFiDirect`. In the `StreamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived` event, the event parameter contains the established StreamSocket. About the use of `WiFiDirect` with `StreamSocketListener`, you can check [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WiFiDirect)

Comment: Hi @Richard, I have gone through that sample code. I should listen for `StreamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived` if android is trying to connect UWP as server, not when Android itself create server socket. In Android side I am creating socket based gropu-owner information which i can not know in UWP side.  Am i wrong thinking this way?

Comment: Hello, According to your needs, you can choose StreamSocketListener (as a server) or StreamSocket (as a connector), depending on your purpose. These are two different behaviors. What you have to do is similar to your current workaround. You need to create an identifier (variable) for judgment, but `EndpointPair` itself does not contain similar information.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT, should i declare that identifier in UWP side?what should be the value of that identifier ?

Comment: Hello, the purpose of this identifier is to judge the current connection method, which is judged inside the UWP, so this identifier is a variable defined in the UWP application, has nothing to do with Android, and will not be passed with the Socket. This identifier can be a Boolean value. (For example, there are two buttons in the application, one of which is used as a server and the other as a connector. The application changes the identifier according to the different buttons the user clicks and creates a corresponding connection)